# Should I use docker (nginx) for serving a SPA?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, docker, containers, single-page-application

I only have 1 javascript file(bundle.js packed by webpack) and 1 html. It's kinda like SPA.
I'm thinking how I host this SPA? I already have one clean VM on Amazon EC2.
I was planning setup a docker (Nginx) on this EC2. However, as I said, this VM is clean. Only this SPA will use this EC2 VM.
So I'm confused by this situation. Should I use docker(nginx) or just install a Nginx on this EC2 for serving this SPA?

Comment: If you dont plan to have a backend, you shouldn't use VM at all. Could you verify S3 static web hosting is all you might need?

Comment: Yes. S3 definitely can help me. However, someday I may change the service provider(AWS). So, I prefer the traditional way of using VM.
I'm just wondering if I need the Docker on this simple case.

Answer (score 2):

AWS S3 service is capable of service static files, You just need to upload your files to a bucket, then make them public and note the public URL.

As a side note, Containerizing apps and using microservices architecture, will give you advantages, Some of them are:

- Ease of Upgrade
- Fault Containment
- Ease of technology change
- Increased Security
- Efficient Resource Utilization

Comment: Yes. I have considered this solution (S3). However, someday I may change the service provider(AWS). So, I prefer the traditional way of using VM.
I'm just wondering if I need the Docker on this simple case.

Comment: with docker: If you plan software upgrades, in your case nginx update to newer version, it will be as easy of an image pull, same goes for faster roll back if the newer version fails, It will makes your life much easier. You can also aggregate multiple apps on the same machine, With high level of Isolation.

Answer (score 1):

S3 is cheap enough for static files, almost free compared to EC2 unless you have backend in place. You can use [Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io) for S3 and if you want to go FTP one day, same app would give you a common UX for uploading your files.

Though Docker setup would be over engineering for static serving in IaaS, you would need to build an image that contains nginx and your files as in [KyleAMathews/docker-nginx](https://github.com/KyleAMathews/docker-nginx) project.